# How do I remove trailing and leading white space from items in a list in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

Say I have a list:
my_list = ['  John Jones ', 'Betty Birch  ', '  David Davis ']

What method can I use to remove all the white space around the names? (not the space in between first and last names).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove leading and trailing spaces but not in between the words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24926295/remove-leading-and-trailing-spaces-but-not-in-between-the-words)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.strip` function in python. Using it in list comprehension.

```
my_list = [x.strip() for x in my_list]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I was looking for.